# Image classification for a study site falling over two adjacent Landsat 8 scenes using QGIS or ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: raster, merge, classification, landsat-8

I will be using GRASS on OSX to classify Landsat 8 geotiff images to create a vegetation map for a study site that happens to fall over 2 separate Landsat scenes.

I seek advice about which route to take and I'm not able to find any other information about this elsewhere:

1.) Should I **FIRST** find a way to combine the 2 scenes together (which presumably would require combining the 2 scenes of each channel separately - would that be right?), and then cut out the small area covered by my study site and THEN start the classification process.

OR

2.) Should I conduct image classification on the 2 adjacent Landsat scenes separately and then combine right at the end? (Although I'm worried this will take much longer, not to mention use up more memory - the study site I am working with is only 1400 km2)

Answer (score 1):

Anytime imagery was acquired at different time periods you will always need to do atmospheric correction. In GRASS you can use the [i.atcorr](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/i.atcorr.html) tool to perform the atmospheric correction.

Once the scenes are atmospherically corrected, you can proceed with your image classification knowing that atmospheric effects such as Rayleigh scattering will be minimized.